# Magento 1.7.0.2 add a second paypal module for credit cards

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.7

I already uses PayPal as a payment method but I want to add the option to use credit card. I know you can use it by choosing the paypal option but my customer/friend want people to be able to choose it directly but still being transferred to paypal's website credit card payment.

-Credit Card
-Paypal
-Invoice

Can anyone help me figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Paypal Payments  pro. 
You can follow these magentocommerce links to configure paypal payments pro in your magento store,

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/paypal-payments-pro-workflow-for-magento-community

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/getting-started-with-paypal-payments-pro-for-magento-community

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-payments-pro-for-magento-community

Comment: That's not what im looking for, we want to add another paypal option that is exactly as Paypal Payments Standard but uses "SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing", I need to like duplicate the module that's already existing and add this?

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I dont have Paypal Pro so i need to find a way to add this functionality?

Comment: As you effectively want 2 'paypal standard' implementations you will need to create a custom payment module which extends the PayPal standard models and then override the function which generates the request going to paypal to cater for your new attributes (check the redirect template from memory as well). I wouldn't simply copy the paypal module as you will not benefit from updates/bug fixes released by Magento so create your own payment module and extend the default magento one. PayPal Magento module can be complicated but should be straight forward to change the request on redirect.

Comment: @AshleySwatton could you possibly help me to create a payment module of this kind? I've tried following all the guides I could find but non seams to work.